# Reading comprehension n2

Tags: translation, reading-comprehension

Why are 3 and 5 incorrect? Also what does ほら mean in this instance?

[image]

Comment: Would you please provide me the title is the book that page is from?

Comment: sure! it's from Nihongo So-matome: Essential Practice for the Japanese Language Proficiency Test (JLPT), Level N2, Reading

Answer (score 3):

> いつも通る道の、ほらベンチがあるところ、なんだかゴミだらけだと思わない？

- > □ 3　学校のベンチの周りは、ゴミでいっぱいである。

The bench is not at the school, but on the route the speaker always takes. ほら is just to call attention, maybe like "y'know".

---

> ね、うちのクラブでゴミ箱作ってそこへ置くっていうのはどう？美術部に絵をかいてもらってさ。

- > □ 5　ベンチにかく絵を美術部に頼む予定である。

The picture should go on the litter bin / garbage can the speaker is wanting to make, not on the bench.

Comment: Could 絵 refer to a blueprint or something like that?

Comment: @kuchitsu No, it's something [like this](https://stock.adobe.com/images/trashcan-in-yard-with-flower-painting/32013119?prev_url=detai).